# PHP file_get_contents() confusion with URL in variable

Tags: php, variables, file-get-contents

This is my first question I hope to get best guidance.

I'm trying to grab the content of a webpage using `file_get_contents()`.
In many occasions it's working fine, but there is one thing that is driving me crazy.

I'm separating a long link into three parts and put it back together with the code below. The link is a pagination link and the "3" is responsible for indicating the page, so in this particular link I want to see page 3.

```
$combinedlink = $firstpart."3".$secondpart."3".$thirdpart."1445256372";
$input = file_get_contents($combinedlink);
```

When I now echo $input, it is showing me page 1 instead of 3. When I echo the $combinedlink and follow it, it is taking me to the correct page. Now the shocking part: When I copy the output of echo $combinedlink; and insert it like this:

```
$input = file_get_contents("http://www.ReallyLongLink.de/EvenMoreStuff");
```

It is working fine and takes me to page 3. But the variable contains exactly the right thing but it is only working when I hard-code the link. `Var_dump` also shows me String(178) and then the string in quotationmarks.

Comment: your `$combinedLink` seems to be wrong. There **is** no other explanation for your observation. `file_get_contents` does not care if its a variable or hardcoded string - if the two are equal, then you should get the same result. (If the result would only be different for native browsing, then it might me some meta-refreshes on the target server that `file_get_contents` does not follow. Then You need curl with follow_redirects)

Comment: what do you see when you `echo $combinedlink;`?

Comment: if you are actually doing `$combinedlink = $firstpart."3".$secondpart."3".$thirdpart."1445256372";` then `$combinedlink` simply cannot be `"http://www.ReallyLongLink.de/EvenMoreStuff"` as you stated

Comment: I have a link like this: `http://www.thispage.de/page=1/morestuff`

After doing this: 
`$combinedlink = $firstpart."3".$secondpart."3".$thirdpart."1445256372;`
it returns this: 
`http://www.thispage.de/page=3/morestuff`

Comment: Your generated link does not show the second "3" - please provide real example data (Before, your logic to get the parts, and after) or wait for the guy with the crystal ball :-)

Comment: That's impossible again. Just show what you are really doing and what you really wants to achieve

Comment: I'm trying to crawl products from an online store using pagination links. Everything works fine when I hardcode the link. For example in this loop $crawl2 works, but $crawl1 shows always page 1 and is not incrementing, even though when echoed it is exactly the same link

`for($p = 1; $p < 10; $p++){ $crawl1 = $first.$p.$second.$p.$third; $crawl2 = "http://www.somepage.de/s/ref=sr_pg_".$p."?rh=n%3A77028031%2Cn%3A%2178689031%2Cn‌​%3A1981001031%2Cn%3A1981002031%2Cn%3A1981003031%2Cn%3A1981004031&page=".$p."&ie=U‌​TF8&qid=1445085907"; }`

Comment: So there must be something wrong when I combine the link with the three different parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website you are trying to crawl might be using some other means of pagination besides the URL, such as a cookie/ session. That might explain why the link works in your browser but not in your script.

To track cookies sent by the website, you may want to try using a library, such as  [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/), to fetch the pages.

**UPDATED**

```
$input = file_get_contents(html_entity_decode($combinedlink));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it works when I hardcode the link and simply exchange the pagination number with a variable. In the following example fails $crawl1, but $crawl2 is succesful, even thought both are exactly the same when echoed

`for($p = 1; $p < 10; $p++){
$crawl1 = $first.$p.$second.$p.$third;
$crawl2 = "http://www.somepage.de/s/ref=sr_pg_".$p."?rh=n%3A77028031%2Cn%3A%2178689031%2Cn%3A1981001031%2Cn%3A1981002031%2Cn%3A1981003031%2Cn%3A1981004031&page=".$p."&ie=UTF8&qid=1445085907";
}`

Comment: I can only guess that it's an issue with some other part of code in the loop. If it works without the variables `$first`, `$second`, `$third`, why are they required?

Comment: Because I crawl an online store by node-link, for example: 
`http://www.somepage.de/b?node=192838845`

And on this node page extract the pagination link, replace the page number with my variables, and continue with the next node link
The pagination link would be the long one from my previous comment

Comment: I'm sorry, but without more code, I can't help. There's no logical reason, if `$crawl1 === $crawl2`, that one should work and not the other.

Comment: And this is the weird thing: Even though when echoed they are looking exactly the same, but as soon as I try this: `$crawl1 === $crawl2` it says they re not equal. So there must be something wrong with my concatenation

Comment: Do they both have the same length? Try comparing the outputs of `var_dump()`.

Comment: $crawl1 is 22 characters longer somehow. Trying to find out why at the moment

Comment: And the outputs of `var_dump($crawl1)` and `var_dump($crawl2)`?

Comment: `var_dump` shows a linebreak after the first questionmark that `echo` does not show

Comment: `?rh=n%3A77028031%2Cn%3A%2178689031%2Cn%3A1981001031%2Cn%3A1981002031%2Cn%3A1981003031%2Cn%3A1981004031&page=2&ie=UTF8&qid=14452651971`
versus 
`?rh=n%3A77028031%2Cn%3A%2178689031%2Cn%3A1981001031%2Cn%3A1981002031%2Cn%3A1981003031%2Cn%3A1981004031&page=2&ie=UTF8&qid=1445265197`

Comment: A single carriage return can't account for a 22 character difference. What else is different?

Comment: See for yourself: Complete output of vardumping the two variables.

`string(178) "http://www.somepage.de/s/ref=sr_pg_3?rh=n%3A77028031%2Cn%3A%2178689031%2Cn%3A1981001031%2Cn%3A1981002031%2Cn%3A1981003031%2Cn%3A1981004031&page=3&ie=UTF8&qid=1445256372" 
string(166) "http://www.somepage.de/s/ref=sr_pg_3?rh=n%3A77028031%2Cn%3A%2178689031%2Cn%3A1981001031%2Cn%3A1981002031%2Cn%3A1981003031%2Cn%3A1981004031&page=3&ie=UTF8&qid=1445256372"`

Comment: The shorter one is the working one. And sorry, I meant 12 not 22, my bad

Comment: Can you try trimming each of the part variables? `trim($first)`, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately the same output

Comment: In case it helps: all three parts combined have the same `strlen` as the working string. The additional 12 characters seem to come from the additions I'm making to the three parts. Maybe I didn't replace the values but they are just hiding somehow?

Comment: Can you paste the outputs of `var_dump(base64_encode($crawl1));` and `var_dump(base64_encode($crawl2));` ?

Comment: Output of $crawl1:
`string(240) "aHR0cDovL3d3dy5hbWF6b24uZGUvcy9yZWY9c3JfcGdfMz9yaD1uJTNBNzcwMjgwMzElMkNuJTNBJTIxNzg2ODkwMzElMkNuJTNBMTk4MTAwMTAzMSUyQ24lM0ExOTgxMDAyMDMxJTJDbiUzQTE5ODEwMDMwMzElMkNuJTNBMTk4MTAwNDAzMSZhbXA7cGFnZT0zJmFtcDtpZT1VVEY4JmFtcDtxaWQ9MTQ0NTI1NjM3Mg=="`

$crawl2: 

`string(224)
"aHR0cDovL3d3dy5hbWF6b24uZGUvcy9yZWY9c3JfcGdfMz9yaD1uJTNBNzcwMjgwMzElMkNuJTNBJTIxNzg2ODkwMzElMkNuJTNBMTk4MTAwMTAzMSUyQ24lM0ExOTgxMDAyMDMxJTJDbiUzQTE5ODEwMDMwMzElMkNuJTNBMTk4MTAwNDAzMSZwYWdlPTMmaWU9VVRGOCZxaWQ9MTQ0NTI1NjM3Mg=="`

Comment: Got It! The problem is that the ampersands (&) are escaped in the `$crawl1`. You have to `html_entity_decode($crawl1)`.

Comment: Oh god I think I'm in love now. Thanks alot for all your effort!!